# Script doesn't exit from function when send error report

Tags: bash, scripting, function

when i launch my script, it still remains in process while function goes in error after send the mail:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/data/logs/file.log
DATE="$(date +%Y%m%d --date="1 day ago")"
##### STEPS #####

### STEP 1:

step_1(){
curl --location --request GET "http://url"
sleep 1m

if  grep -q 'completed!' $LOG_FILE | tail -1 ;then
        report_step_1
        step_2
else
        report_error_step_1
        exit 1
fi
}

### STEP 2:

step_2(){
curl --location --request GET "http://url"
sleep 30m
if  grep -q 'Generete Revenue File completed' $LOG_FILE | tail -1 ;then
        report_step_2
        step_3
else
        report_error_step_2
        exit 1
fi
}

### STEP 3:

step_3(){
curl --location --request GET "http:url"
sleep 30m
if  grep -q 'File correctly sent via ftp' $LOG_FILE | tail -3 ;then
        report_step_3
else
        report_error_step_3
        exit 1
fi
}

report_step_1(){
mail -s "OK" "mail" <<< "STEP 1 completato con successo"
}

report_step_2(){
mail -s "OK" "mail" <<< "STEP 2 completato con successo"
}

report_step_3(){
mail -s "OK" "mail" <<< "STEP 3 completato con successo"
}

report_error_step_1(){
mail -s "FAILED" "mail" <<< "Attenzione: STEP 1 fallito"
exit 5
}

report_error_step_2(){
mail -s "FAILED" "mail" <<< "Attenzione: STEP 2 fallito"
exit 5
}

report_error_step_3(){
mail -s "FAILED" "mail" <<< "Attenzione: STEP 3 fallito"
exit 5
}

step_1
exit 0
```

Could somebody take a look and tell my why exit don't work and if i have correctly configured all exit in the other functions?

Comment: Does that occur for _all_ error conditions, or only for some? At which step does the script send the error?

Comment: Script start with step_1...if ok goes to function report_step_1 and then step_2....if KO goes to report_error_step_1 but after sending the email, script is still working...and don't exit. I need to know if exit 4 and exit 5 are correctly setted becouse it's still remains running. And if other exit are correctly

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: i changed something using shellcheck but it still remains running. i don't know if i wrote my script uncorrectly...i only need to make 3 curl in sequence. Then grep the log file and if it found completed, goes to step 2 and send email OK. If not, send email KO and then exit from the script

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a _minimal_ script that reproduces the problem. This will also help you debug it. Just remove everything you don't need and give us a few lines of code that we can use to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: i've modified the script. Since the curl are not avaiable to test, just have a log file in which to put a line in completed if you want to go on with the steps and one in failed if you want it to pass to the function of report_error_step_X

Comment: Try removing the "!" in the following "grep -q 'completed!' ", that is, use "grep -q 'completed' " instead and see of that works for you.

Comment: Also, your "if..then" statements are not being evaluated correctly - they are always 0. In a bash shell, type "grep -q 'completed' file.log" where the word 'completed' is in the file.log. Then type "echo $?" immediately afterwards - which is the status of the last command typed - it evaluates to "0". This implies your "if...then" statements are failing.

Comment: So break up the conditional statement into: value=\`grep 'completed' ${LOG_FILE} | tail -1\` (note I'm using a back pipe) and then the conditional statement becomes: if[ ${value} = "completed" ]; then .....